# How Quickly does the Soil Erode in Banished?

Tags: banished

I read somewhere that planting the same crop over and over again will produce smaller yields overtime, but how do you know when to switch crops?

Does it follow the same pattern as farming where they plant something like corn one year, beans the next to return nutrients to the soil, and then leave it fallow for a year?

Does leaving the a plot fallow have any benefit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is true for the real world, and should be for the game, it is not. It is/was planned but never made it to game for now.

> Though, the developer has confirmed that soil degradation has not been
>   implemented.

[Source](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Farming)

Unfortunately updates seem to be pretty spare these day.

Regarding comment:

> It is important to note that crop fields can become infested, this will destroy the entire crop. It also means that if the same crop is planted in the same area again they will have a much greater chance of being infected, as such it is recommended to plant a new type of crop in the field next year.

Source is same as above

Comment: But, does the infestation mechanic have the same effect with forcing the player to rotate crops?

Comment: @user3554664 i do not completly understand you, but i updated my answer regarding infestation which yes, does force you to change your crop because it increases the chance to come again if you dont.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. How do you avoid infestation? Is the way to avoid it by rotating the crops?

Comment: @user3554664 Ah, no it is not, it is just a random event.